# How to estimate EF migration time

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first, database-migration

In my project I have EF Code First, in one deploy I add one column and copmute it value by other columns/tables. When I update code to test env everything go fast, but on prod enviroment it take long time, becouse prod env contains much more entries.

My question is how can I prevent this situation? Is any tool to estimate (not execute) migration time on specified database?

Comment: Basing on such estimation in my opinion will always be unreliable. Execution time depends usually on various factors like calculation load on the server during the execution, data in the database. Each time it may be completely different. Is one part of your migration code dependant on the result of the other? In such case make Sql instruction invoking the codes part of the same transaction - Sql method has second parameter of type bool - should be false.